# Salesforce Validation rule issue on compound field

Tags: salesforce

I have created a validation rule for a compound address custom field. The country field is populated by default. The validation rule is supposed to show an error message if the following conditions are met:

The value of the lived_since__c field is Less than 2 years.
The values of the Previous_Address_StateCode_s, Previous_Address_Street_s, Previous_Address_PostalCode_s, and Previous_Address_City_s fields are all blank.
However, I am seeing different behavior. Only the Previous_Address_StateCode_s field is working. If I remove this field from the validation rule, then only one of the other fields is working.
I have created a following formula.

I have wrote the following validation rule.
    `AND( ISPICKVAL(lived_since__c, 'Less than 2 years'), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_StateCode_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_Street_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_PostalCode_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_City_s) )`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to check each of those custom fields you have made like: `ISBLANK(Previous_Address_StateCode_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_Street_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_PostalCode_s), ISBLANK(Previous_Address_City_s) ).`

Each of these attributes values needs to be checked as if they are ***NOT BLANK*** then obviously you're validation message won't show up.

Use a SOQL Query to validate their values or create formula fields using those fields or even checking with a Salesforce Inspector.